# Issue in accessing the particular value from json

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following json

```
var data=
{
"soapenv:Envelope" : {
    "xmlns:soapenv" : "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
    "soapenv:Body" : {
        "CallBankChatBotResponse" : {
            "xmlns" : "http://ST/CallBankChatBot.tws",
            "responseMessage" : "2072.4145"
        }
    }
  }
};
```

Now I need the value of responseMessage i.e.,2072.4145

If json is normal I can easily get that value.But here if I try it is geving me error because of special character :
then

```
data.soapenv:Envelope.xmlns:soapenv.soapenv:Body.CallBankChatBotResponse.responseMessage
```

will not work.How can I get the responseMessage value by escaping :

Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

You could use bracket notation to access there `responseMessage`

```
var result = data["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["CallBankChatBotResponse"]["responseMessage"];
```

Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Sry.This didnt worked.Giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'soapenv:Body' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can use bracket notation, then you can keep keys as strings in quotes. To get responseMessage, you can do something like this:

```
data["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["CallBankChatBotResponse"]["responseMessage"]
```

```js
var data=
{
"soapenv:Envelope" : {
"xmlns:soapenv" : "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
"soapenv:Body" : {
    "CallBankChatBotResponse" : {
        "xmlns" : "http://ST/CallBankChatBot.tws",
        "responseMessage" : "2072.4145"
    }
}
  }
};

console.log(data["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["CallBankChatBotResponse"]["responseMessage"]
);
```

Comment: Sry.This didnt worked.Giving TypeError: Cannot read property 'soapenv:Body' of undefined

Comment: it seems to be working in the snippet above. your error means `data["soapenv:Envelope"]` is returning undefined, check your json object again.